# How do I properly use the WaitForSingleObject method to wait for an external program to terminate?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I'm trying to launch an external application with elevated status, and wait until it exits before continuing:

```
var
  FProcess: THandle;
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin

  FillChar(ExecInfo, SizeOf(ExecInfo), 0);
  with ExecInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
    fMask := 0;
    Wnd := AWindow;
    lpVerb := 'runas';
    lpFile := PChar(APath);
    lpParameters := PChar(AParams);
    lpDirectory := PChar(AWorkDir);
    nShow := SW_NORMAL;
  end;

  Result := ShellExecuteEx(@ExecInfo);

  if Wait then
  begin
    while WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT do
      Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
```

This launches, but it just keeps waiting.  The calling program never continues past the call to WaitForSingleObject, even after the called program exits.

I've tried WAIT_OBJECT_0 instead of WAIT_TIMEOUT, but I have the same problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What process are you attempting to execute? Are you sure it succeeded? If it did, are you sure you got a valid handle? There's a lot of stuff that could go wrong in that code before you ever get to the part you're asking about. Make sure you're asking about the right thing. And if the WaitForSingleObject call returns, it clearly isn't returning Wait_Timeout; so what *is* it returning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What the code

```
while WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT do
  Application.ProcessMessages;
```

is supposed to do? It is an infinite loop.

Use just

```
WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

instead. And yes, you need

```
fMask:= SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
```

to obtain the process handle.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is broken.  You are not passing the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag to `ShellExecuteEx()`, so it will not return a valid process handle to you, and your loop is ignoring the errors that `WaitForSingleObject()` tells you because of that, so you end up in an endless loop.

Try this instead:

```
var
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@ExecInfo, SizeOf(ExecInfo));
  with ExecInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    Wnd := AWindow;
    lpVerb := 'runas';
    lpFile := PChar(APath);
    lpParameters := PChar(AParams);
    lpDirectory := PChar(AWorkDir);
    nShow := SW_NORMAL;
  end;
  Result := ShellExecuteEx(@ExecInfo);
  if Result and Wait then
  begin
    if ExecInfo.hProcess <> 0 then // no handle if the process was activated by DDE
    begin
      repeat
        if MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, ExecInfo.hProcess, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT) = (WAIT_OBJECT_0+1) then
          Application.ProcessMessages
        else
          Break;
      until False;
      CloseHandle(ExecInfo.hProcess);
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: How do you get the `ExitCode` from the called process with this method?

Comment: Call [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189.aspx) after the loop exits and before you close the process handle.

Answer (score 2):

If you read [description of ShellExecuteEx in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will see this:

> hProcess
>
> ```
> Type: HANDLE
> ```
>
> A handle to the newly started application. This member is set on
>   return and is always NULL unless fMask
>   is set to SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS.
>   Even if fMask is set to
>   SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS, hProcess will
>   be NULL if no process was launched.

I.e. you simply don't have a valid handle. You need to set fMask as written above.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  After changing the fMask accordingly, it still locks up the calling application.